# Unkillable Advantage and the afterlife

Tags: gm-techniques, gurps-4e

In a GURPS 4e campaign, when a character dies, I want it to run through an afterlife, which would be easy to escape (maybe a combat or a few puzzles, like a variation on the [Halls of Mandos](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Halls_of_Mandos)), and then be back to life.

The situation seems similar to the Unkillable 3 Advantage (It is found in the GURPS 4e Basic Set - Characters, page 95): The characters will appear, fully healed but in the afterlife and unable to directly affect anything (without speaking to the dead or some such), and they will exit the afterlife at a specific location.

Since death wouldn't matter, should I just grant all the characters the Advantage Unkillable? Is there a better way to handle this scenario by the RAW? (There are a lot of them, you know.)

Comment: Would enemies have this advantage too, because then it is just a common trait, and you don't need to have every character state it.

Comment: @Flotolk I intend on the characters having been specially picked (without their knowledge) by a deity to keep living, so that the afterlife tests are easier. They'll eventually notice that *their* tests are a lot easier than the ones being offered the NPCs (who always fail), and that should lead to an epiphany that something is up.

Comment: In that case, I would give them this advantage BUT it wouldn't be written on their sheets, just in your GM notes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mechanically, it doesn't matter: either they're building 300-point characters with 150 points pre-allocated to Unkillable 3, or they're building 150-point characters with a secret 150-point Unkillable 3 advantage they don't know about. The numbers work out the same either way. If you want to keep that advantage secret, then just tell them to build 150-point characters, and don't sweat the details on exactly how much your resurrection method costs.

Since "you must pass some easy tests" is a condition of Unkillable 3, that's a limitation that will tweak the exact point cost. Just save yourself the headache and don't worry about how to represent that advantage on the character sheets: the afterlife works the way you say it works, because you're the GM and you're affecting all of the player characters equally.